# How to debug/Inspect WKWebView for mac Catalyst app ? (Debugging WKWebView stopped working after MacOS update 13.2)

Tags: xcode, safari, wkwebview, mac-catalyst, macos-ventura

I want to debug/inspect my mac Catalyst app in safari. Earlier I was able to do it but after macOS 13.2 update. My app or any mac Catalyst app is not listing in Safari -> Develop menu.

[image]

But for Mac App(AppKit) and if I run an iOS app in simulator then it show the app in safari -> develop.